# JavaFX TableView Not Displaying

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am having a problem with my TableView when i try to import data to it from a 2D Array.  I have the following code in the `initialize()` method:

```
        //String[][] studentArray = stuList.toArray();
        String[][] studentArray = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd"},  {"dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd"}};



        ObservableList<String[]> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(studentArray);
        data.addAll(Arrays.asList(studentArray));
 //       TableView<String[]> table = new TableView<>();
 //       UserId.setCellfactory();
        studTable.setItems(data);
```

When it is run the table will display the rows and they are selectable but there is no data displayed.  I have looked at other examples and they seem to imply that I need some sort of cellFactory methods or something, but I don't understand how to implement them. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

using TableView is not that simply. Your table isn't displaying data because it doesn't know which data to display. To use TableView you must define its columns, also you must define properties to columns. Here is a detailed [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJABHGAJ). You can create a new class for your data and use it for TableView.